# Systemstack error: level too deep after running db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I got a bit messed up while removing a few models, so I decided to drop my whole table and rerun the migrations to have fresh start. However, after running db:seed (even if the seed is entirely empty) I get the following error:

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

I have no idea where this is coming from. I have been looking at this question, but none of the solutions seems to apply on my situation. I don't really understand where I should be looking at, so if more information is required to help me: please tell me!

Since some state that it could be problem with gems, here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I guess you should show full backtrace.

Comment: run `rake db:seed --trace`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably accidentally calling a method from within its definition or something similar resulting in recursion.

Using `rake db:seed --trace` should help show which methods are filling up the call stack. If that crashes before giving you a trace you can try some more advanced tools like https://github.com/tmm1/stackprof